# GHC, Simple Performance Test yields batcrazy sawtooth graph

Tags: haskell

I am trying to do some very simple performance testing in Haskell using the `clock` library and code that looks like this

```
timeBefore <- getTime Monotonic
--do something
timeAfter <- getTime Monotonic

putStrLn $ show $ toNanoSecs (timeAfter `diffTimeSpec` timeBefore)
```

This works, but the times are a bit noisy, so I repeat multiple times to get an average, like this

```
replicateM_ 10000 $ do
  timeBefore <- getTime Monotonic
  --something
  timeAfter <- getTime Monotonic

  putStrLn $ show $ toNanoSecs (timeAfter `diffTimeSpec` timeBefore)
```

This also works, until I remove the underscore from `replicateM_` (in an attempt to return all the times to calculate an average....  but the problem happens even when I don't return numerical values).  As soon as I replace `replicateM_` with `replicateM`, the values scrolling by started to look pretty erratic, and often very large.  Confused, I graphed the result and was pretty surprised at what I saw

[image]

This is completely bizarre....  It looks like the overall program is constantly slowing down and speeding up in a sawtooth fashion.  I can't imagine what would cause this to happen (something to do with garbage collection?  Something to do with memory allocation for a bunch of returned `()`s?).  Note that the baseline timing values I get with the underscore 'replicateM_' is about 100nm, so all of the sawtooth behavior is *adding* to the overall time, by two orders of magnitude.

The weird behavior remains when I remove literally everything from my source code but this

```
module Main where

import           Control.Monad
import           System.Clock

main :: IO ()
main = do
  replicateM_ 10000 $ do
    timeBefore <- getTime Monotonic
    --I don't even need to put anything here for the problem to exist
    timeAfter <- getTime Monotonic
    putStrLn $ show $ toNanoSecs (timeAfter `diffTimeSpec` timeBefore)

  return ()
```

All you need to do is add or remove that underscore, and the times go from an expected 100nm flat line to the batcrazy sawtooth that jumps from 100nm to 8000nm over and over again.

What am I missing here?

Comment: GC is a good guess - as more and more heap is allocatec the copying collector has more work.  I had a similar, though less pronounced, benchmark issue due (I believe) to intel cpu frequency scaling and thermal profiles.  Ultimately, it seems unlikely anyone here can tell you with certainty what is going on since you didn't share the full system.  Best I'd hope for in your position is educated guessing and people telling you to do it correctly via a benchmarking library.

Comment: You're almost certainly seeing the cost of the garbage collector traversing something that is still alive repeatedly, until it's finally freed and the GC doesn't have to traverse it to reclaim the memory.  Given that the key difference is `mapM` vs `mapM_`, it has to be the list `mapM` produces.  All other details depend on things like runtime options, ghc version, and compile flags.

Comment: If you really just need the mean, don't capture the times; just calculate the sum as you go. If you need more statistics (standard deviation, median, interquartile range, etc.), then you should consider recording the times in an (unboxed) array or vector instead of a list.

Comment: Nobody mentioned Criterion yet?